# Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, dao, jdbctemplate

I have an Error in JDBCTemplate. 
 Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of com.xurpas.util.hitsRowMapper.  Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
inc_var.getType= "Select type from table group by type"

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getType(String table){
            JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
            inc_var.getType = inc_var.getType.replace("$table", table);
            logger.LogFile("EDIT: " + inc_var.getType);
            return getJdbcTemplate.queryForList(inc_var.getType, new hitsRowMapper());      
        }


public class hitsRowMapper implements RowMapper<Object> {

    //@Override
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        hitsRowExtractor ext = new hitsRowExtractor();
        return ext.extractData(rs);
    }

public class hitsRowExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor {
     @Override
      public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
         logger.initializeLogger();
        hitsModel hits = new hitsModel();
        hits.setType(rs.getString(1));
        logger.LogFile(rs.getString(1));
        return hits;
      }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer to this problem?